# Adding "frequent / most used" directories to sidebar in PCManFM

Tags: command-line, filemanager

I'm starting to use the mouse a lot more for navigating file directories and I'm really missing the ability to tag directories that MacOS offers. Is there either similar functionality to tag directories or an easy way to add / remove directories from the sidebar in a controlled / non-arbitrary order

I'm sort of hoping there's just a file somewhere with a list of paths and labels that I can write a function to edit.

desired function would work like so

add path or current `.` directory to list

```
$ adir /home/lukes/dev/this/folder xyz 
$ :) added /home/lukes/dev to /etc/pcfman/dirlist as xyz
```

Remove a path or current `.` directory from the list

```
$ rdir .
$ :) removed /home/lukes/videos from /etc/pcfman/dirlist
```

Maybe wishful thinking, but figured I'd ask.